# CakePHP find remove fields or recursive find

Tags: cakephp, find, field

I'm trying to slim down my finds queries, by specifying which fields to use. I don't understand how I can specify specific fields for my HABTM fields.

This is my find:

```
$lastviewed = $this->Lastviewedproduct->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Lastviewedproduct.id', 'Lastviewedproduct.sessionid', 'Lastviewedproduct.product_id',
        'Product.id', 'Product.name', 'Product.slug', 'Product.price',
        //'Category.id',
        //'Mediafile.*',
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Lastviewedproduct.status' => 'active',
        'Lastviewedproduct.sessionid' => $this->Session->read('Companyname.sessionid'),
        'Product.hidden_on_site' => 0,
        'Product.visibility' => 1,
        'Product.status' => 'active',
    ),
    'order' => 'Lastviewedproduct.modified DESC',
    'limit' => 5,
    'recursive' => 2,
));
```

This is what it returns:

```
(int) 2 => array(
    'Lastviewedproduct' => array(
        'id' => '97',
        'sessionid' => '14035312318244955',
        'product_id' => '2'
    ),
    'Product' => array(
        'id' => '2',
        'name' => 'blokhut 2',
        'slug' => 'blokhut-2',
        'price' => '200.00',
        'Category' => array(
            (int) 0 => array(
                'id' => '218',
                'zosomodule_id' => '25',
                'user_add_id' => '0',
                'user_update_id' => '0',
                'created' => '2013-11-27 10:00:00',
                'modified' => '2013-11-27 10:00:00',
                'status' => 'active',
                'visibility' => true,
                'parent_id' => '2',
                'shipment_id' => '1',
                'name' => 'Metalen Tuinbergingen ',
                'slug' => 'metalen-tuinbergingen-',
                'pagetitle' => 'Metalen Tuinbergingen ',
                'content' => '<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Metalen tuinbergingen zijn een praktische en kwalitatieve oplossing voor meer bergruimte in uw tuin. Wij hebben diverse merken metalen bergingen zoals </span><span class="s2"><a href="/biohort-avantgarde/">Biohort</a></span><span class="s1">&nbsp;en </span><span class="s2"><a href="/yardmaster-metalen-bergingen/">Yardmaster</a></span><span class="s1">. Hier hebben wij tevens ook tuinkasten en opbergboxen van.</span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1"><br /></span></p>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Mocht u op zoek zijn naar andere varianten tuinbergingen, bekijk dan ons gehele assortiment </span><span class="s2"><a href="/tuinbergingen/">tuinbergingen</a>.</span></p>',
                'metatitle' => 'Metalen tuinbergingen',
                'metadescription' => null,
                'discountoffer' => false,
                'discount_normal' => '0.00',
                'discount_max' => '0.00',
                'discount_ideal' => '0.00',
                'cost_rembours' => '0.00',
                'in_mainmenu' => true,
                'hide_sidebar' => false,
                'show_block' => true,
                'sort_order' => '0',
                'ProductsCategory' => array(
                    'id' => '2',
                    'created' => '2014-01-01 10:00:00',
                    'modified' => '2014-01-01 10:00:00',
                    'product_id' => '2',
                    'category_id' => '218'
                )
            )
        ),
        'Mediafile' => array()
    )
),
```

I don't want all these Category fields, but only `Category.id`, `Category.name` and `Category.slug` for example. How do i say that in my find? As you can see I tried adding `Category.id` in my fields array, but then I get an error. I read something about containable, but I didn't get that working and I don't know if that is the solution.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ContainableBehavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) for this task. You should write something like this:
**1** attach behavior

- permanent

  ```
  class Lastviewedproduct extends AppModel {
      public $actsAs = array('Containable');    
      ....
  }
  ```
- on demand

  ```
  $this->Lastviewedproduct->Behaviors->load('Containable');
  ```

**2** specify fields

```
$this->Lastviewedproduct->find('all', array(
    'contain' => array(
        'Product' => array(
            'Category' => array(
                'fields' => array('id','name','slug')               
            ),            
        ),
        'Mediafile'
    )
));
```

Comment: This works, thanks! I had to add the line in the Model, as Voycey mentioned for it to work. Maybe you can update your answer to make it complete?

Answer (score 0):

Add field parameter with relation ship where you give relationship to Category MODEL

```
public $hasMany = array(
        'Category' => array(
            'className' => 'Category',
            'fields' => array('Category.id','Category.name','Category.slug')
        )
    );
```

Comment: But then I lose the entire Category and Mediafile array. I want to keep them, because I need info from them. I just don't need all their fields. So I have all the information that I need from my find, but I want to slim down my finds so that I only get the necessary fields back. I thought I explained it well in my question.

Comment: Do you mean how my models are bind in their Model.php? They are both hasAndBelongsToMany relationships.

Comment: Yes I want to view that relationship

Comment: Lastviewedproduct has a BelongsTo to Product. Product has a hasAndBelongsToMany to Category and Mediafile. They're just CakePHP generated relationships.

Comment: Have you give dynamic relationship or in Model have you given?

Comment: I don't understand exactly what you mean. The relationships are defined in the corresponding Model.

Comment: I know that I can do it there, but that is not the solution because that way it applies to al my finds. But I want to control in my find itself which fields I need, because it depends of the find which info that I need.

Comment: Then you have to use dynamic binding. Do you know dynamic binding?

Comment: I have a vague memory of it, but I never worked with dynamic binding and don't know how to do that. Can you give an example?

Comment: I tried that with bindModel, but I couldn't get it to work. I tried the other answers and they worked immediately so I went with that answer. I do wanna thank you for your fast help!

Answer (score 0):

As Dimitry said above - [Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) is the way to go with this:

In your Models/AppModel.php (Create it if it doesn't exist) change the call to have the following:

```
class AppModel extends Model {
    public $actsAs = array('Containable');
}
```

Then you would do as Dimitry said above - this will allow you to only return the fields you want.

```
'recursive' => 2
```

will eventually cause you so much slowness that your app will be painful to use, most people set recursive = 1 in their AppModel and use containable the rest of the time.